# Show increase in trendline by using Excel vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, charts

I have data in `c5:c12` (sales1) and I plotted a graph and a trendline of this data. I also have data in `d5:d12` (sales2). I would like to show an increase, graphically, in my existing trendline by using the second data range (by hitting a command button).

How can I achieve this in Excel (by using VBA)?

Comment: Very good question, I had been thinking about this today as well.

Comment: i am glad to hear that it is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step-1: I donot know if you have the developer tab or not in your Excel. If you do not see a "Developer" tab next to your View tab, follow the instructions [here](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/291073). to get it done.

Step-2: As shown below locate the command button and click on it.  This allows you to draw the command button in the location you like.
[image: Locating ActiveX control - command button]

Step-3: Click on the button next to Insert (from Step-2) called Design mode. The background color of this button should change. Now click the command button you placed and it will open your VBE IDE for excel.

Step-4: Enter the following code:

```
     ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLineStacked).Select
     ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("C3:D12")
```

Feel free to change the range **Range("C3:D12")** It should look like this[image]

Step-5: Now clicking the command button should generate the chart that you need.

My Excel sheet looks like this in the end.  What I have done is pretty basic. You can customize tons of things using the same approach.

[image]

Comment: my friend,thank you for your very illustrative answer. this is what i look for:)

Comment: Is there a way of showing these trend lines spliced?(i would like the second trend line to start on the end point of the first trend line)

Comment: I can explain through an example. Look at my example values in Sales 1 and Sales 2 column. If we move the 500,1000.... etc below the 900 level your line will be spliced as you want. Remember to update the range (in the program) after you do this

Comment: Can you give your e mail adress? I want to ask you in more detail.

Comment: prasannarajaram@gmail.com